# Kubuntu 14.10 touchpad middle click problem

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde, synaptics

I just installed the development version of kubuntu 14.10. It use plasma 5. All thigns work correctly but I can't emulate the middle click tapping with two fingers on the touchpad.

I tried to open Settings -> Human input devices but there is only a menu for "Mouse" not for touchpad.

I tried to install kde-touchpad but nothing.

Can somebody help me?

This is the xinput list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 1.3M WebCam                               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**UPDATE**
I modified my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf and add the following line:

```
"TapButton2" "2"
```

I don't think this is a final solution, because in that file is specified:

> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite

but for now it seems to work.

Anyway KDE recognise my touchpad like a mouse....

Comment: What is "Settings -> Human input devices"? My settings are at System settings > Hardware > Input Devices > Touchpad.

Comment: This is a screenshot of my System settings panel http://imageshack.com/a/img905/7151/Kb8bL1.png Have you kubuntu 14.10?

Comment: Ah okay. It might be a translation issue. So what is within that pane? I'm actually using Arch Linux now, but I might still be able to help.

Comment: Keyboard, Mouse and Joystick but not Touchpad

Comment: Ah okay, not sure what else to suggest. If you don't get anything useful here, you can try the KDE forums too.